# How do I ask my teacher for his honest opinion about my capabilities

Tags: university, evaluation

I just ended my internship on bad terms. Both the company and my teachers think that my programming skills are insufficient for a passing grade. We decided to end the internship as continuing would be a waste of time. I now have two options.

1. Take a step back and enrol in a study that is at a somewhat lower level
2. My teachers will train my programming skills. This will take about a year and after that I can look for a new internship. This no guarantee that my programming will be good enough after (depends on myself)

I find it very hard to choose between the two. It's about my future after all. That is why I want to ask one of my teachers for some help. This is the question I would like to ask:

**"You have taught and known me for some years now. Do you think I have it in me to complete option 2 with success and finish a next internship?"**

I realise this is fairly personal question that maybe difficult or awkward to answer. His opinion matters greatly to me however. It would provide me with information to make an educated decision. Some extra details:

- He has been my teacher for almost 7 years
- The atmosphere at the study is fairly informal at times. I can call teachers by their first name for example
- Programming was never my strongest asset
- I tend to overestimate my programming skills so an outside opinion is greatly appreciated

What I would like to know is how to approach this. Do I send him an e-mail with this question or do I ask it in person? I would also imagine that someone has to think about this type of question. Or should I request a meeting to discuss this? Or not ask at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your teachers have offered to train you, it is highly unlikely that they don't believe you capable. It probably wouldn't be in either their interest or yours to continue if they thought you weren't.

Having said that, in your position, I would still seek guidance from your teacher. The way I'd go about it is to speak to your teacher face to face and say something like:

"I'd like to take the opportunity you offered to train my programming skills. Could I set up some time with you to discuss what I need to change in order to be successful this time?"

And go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I'm still enrolled and pay tuition so basically they have to help me as long as I'm a student there. That doesn't take away that they are willing to make a study plan just for me which is a huge favour in my opinion. I've edited my question. Arranging a meeting is still a good idea. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Iarwain Not necessarily. Good teachers will be looking after the interests of their students too. If they believe that you don't have the aptitude to succeed they should be having that conversation with you. It would be quite unprofessional if they were just stringing you along, with no hope, just to collect the fees. However, this seems unlikely given, as you say, that they're going out of their way to help you.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I have spoken with said teacher. I send him an email outlining that I appreciate his opinion and honesty and would like his assessment. I got an email back where he flipped the question around and asked me to deeply reflect on the years I spend pursuing this study. I accepted your answer because asking him was a good move. He told me exactly at what level (he thinks) my skills are at. My apologies for accepting your answer so late